# sed command to comment out whole block of curly braces, by searching some string before block start

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have some files which contains blocks like below:

```
   public return_type var_name {get; set;}

   public return_type var2_name {
        get { if (some_condition) {some_code} else {some_code}} set; }

   public return_type var3_name {
        get { 
              if (some_condition) 
              {
                some_code
              } 
              else {
                     some_code
                   }
                }
   }
```

so sed command should comment whole block of say var2_name or var3_name. It should search for the variable and comment the block of that variable.

Required Output:

```
   public return_type var_name {get; set;}

   // public return_type var2_name {
   //     get { if (some_condition) {some_code} else {some_code}} set; }

   //public return_type var3_name {
   //     get { 
   //           if (some_condition) 
   //           {
   //             some_code
   //           } 
   //           else {
   //                  some_code
   //                }
   //             }
   //}
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution (assuming that multilined function definitions don't have empty lines inside):

```
awk '/\<var[23]_name\>/{ f=1 }f && NF{ $0="//"$0 }!NF{ f=0 }1' file
```

The output:

```
public return_type var_name {get; set;}

//public return_type var2_name {
//     get { if (some_condition) {some_code} else {some_code}} set; }

//public return_type var3_name {
//     get { 
//           if (some_condition) 
//           {
//             some_code
//           } 
//           else {
//                  some_code
//                }
//             }
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this question is that regular expressions do not have the possibility to match corresponding parentheses. So you need to keep track of the count yourself.

In the following solution I make the following assumptions :

- The closing parentheses of the block in question is the last bracket of the line.

The following awk will then do the trick :

```
awk 'function count_braces(str) { return gsub(/{/,"",str) - gsub(/}/,"",str) }
     BEGIN{count=-1}
     /var2_name|var3_name/{ count=count_braces($0);
                            print "//",$0; next }
     (count > 0) { print "//",$0;
                   count=count+count_braces($0);
                   next }
     {print $0}' <file>
```

and gives the output :

```
  public return_type var_name {get; set;}

//    public return_type var2_name {
//         get { if (some_condition) {some_code} else {some_code}} set; }

//    public return_type var3_name {
//         get { 
//               if (some_condition) 
//               {
//                 some_code
//               } 
//               else {
//                      some_code
//                    }
//                 }
//    }
```

Remark that in this solution, `var2_name` or `var3_name` should not appear in any other context. It might be better to have an improved regex like `/^[[:blank:]]*public return type (var2_name|var3_name)/`.